# RestTemplate no suitable HttpMessageConverter found

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm using spring 4. I'm trying to call restTemplate.postForEntity but keep getting

```
no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class java.lang.Object] and content type [text/html]
```

My rest template configuration:

```
<bean id="restTemplate" name="restTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate"
    autowire-candidate="true">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpClientFactory" />

    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My function call:

```
protected <T> T doExecute(String suffixUrl, MultiValueMap<String, String> requestBody, Class<T> responseType) {

    String prefixUrl = "https://blabla.com/api/bla/";
    ResponseEntity<T> responseEntity = null;
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(
            "Content-type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(
                                                      requestBody, headers);

    responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(
                            prefixUrl + suffixUrl,
                            request,
                            responseType);

    return responseEntity.getBody();
    }
```

I have a feeling its connected to the response "Content-Encoding: gzip", I've been looking for a gzip converter but it only exists in spring android.

Edit:
This works but its just a workaround:

```
String templateList = this.doExecute(
                                 "list.json",
                                 map,
                                 String .class);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TemplateResponse[] tr = mapper.readValue(
                             templateList,
                             TemplateResponse[].class);
```

Comment: It seems that the server responds with a web page and `T` is `Object`.